# Obtaining the integral of a healpy map

Tags: healpy

I have a healpy map that is the deflection (gradient of the lensing potential), which was obtained during a particular lensing simulation of the CMB. I want to obtain a map of the lensing potential using healpy if possible. I notice that there is a healpy function `alm2map_der1()` which will give me a healpy map and its first derivative given the map's alms. I am assuming this first derivative is the gradient of the map - please correct me if I am wrong. Essentially I want to know if I can use healpy to do the backwards process of this. I want to remove the gradient and I just want the lensing potential.

So far, my attempt has been to use the relation between the deflection and lensing potential power spectra; Cls of deflection = l(l+1) * Cls of lensing potential, and rearranging this to: Cls of lensing potential = Cls of deflection / l(l+1), then using synfast to convert this back into a map. I do not seem to be getting the correct map.

Is there a better way to do what I am trying to do? Maybe even not using healpy?

Answer (score 2):

I can't help with the first part, but I know that converting to the Cls destroys the orientation information. 'synfast' provides a map with the power spectrum that you input but with a random orientation. If I run 'synfast' on a list of Cls with only dipole power, I get a random dipole orientation every time I run:

```
import healpy
healpy.mollview(healpy.synfast([0,1],32,lmax=1))
```

I suggest working only with the alms if you want a map in the end.